# How to connect a Python socket on client-side to Node.js/socket.io?

Tags: python, sockets, node.js, blender

I want to connect Blender (v2.55) to a webpage through sockets.

For the web part, I can use Node.js & socket.io. I've already used a little node.js/socket.io, it's not a problem I think.

Now for Blender, it runs on Python 3.1, so I've already sockets and I can add libraries if needed. I'm new to Python sockets, can I connect a client to node.js/socket.io directly ?

I tried with the basic code from the Python doc:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 8080
data = "Hello from Blender"

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to server and send data
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.send(bytes(data + "\n","utf8"))

# Receive data from the server and shut down
received = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print("Sent:     %s" % data)
print("Received: %s" % received)
```

It results by:

```
Sent:     Hello from Blender
Received: b''
```

It seems that Blender is connected, but doesn't receive data. Also Node shows no new client connected…

Do I need something else ? If somebody can help me out…

Comment: Can you connect to "127.0.0.1", 8080 using telnet or netcat (like `telnet 127.0.0.1 8080`) and send/receive data through telnet? You python script looks ok.

Comment: It's connected but there is no notification on Node side… I used this code before with a Python socket-server, it worked pretty well…

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I've to look at UDP sockets, both for Python and Node.js…

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a protocol/handshake.  What you have there is a bare TCP socket connection.   node.js/socket.io lives on top of a TCP socket.  Basically when you open a connection to a socket.io server, it's expecting you to use some protocol for communication (websockets, longpolling, htmlfile, whatever).  The initial handshake defines what that protocol will be.  Websockets is one of the supported protocols.  [This blog post](http://popdevelop.com/2010/03/a-minimal-python-websocket-server/) should help you.   It doesn't look all that hard to get websockets implemented.

Comment: There also appears to be a Python Websocket Client Library now.  I have not used it - https://github.com/mtah/python-websocket

Comment: I'm trying the python-websocket but I have another problem, I posted about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101621/python-3-1-error-while-adding-a-library-in-blender

Comment: It seems that the blog is down :(

Answer (score 0):

you can try the form of loop to receive valid data.

```
    import socket
    host="127.0.0.1"
    port=8088
    web=socket.socket()
    web.bind((host,port))
    web.listen(5)
    print("recycle")
    while True:
        conn,addr=web.accept()
        data=conn.recv(8)
        print(data)
        conn.sendall(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello world')
        conn.close()
```

and use your browser to visit the host and port for a check

Answer (score 0):

I understand this thread is extremely old. But I faced the same problem recently and couldn't find an answer or any similar questions. So here is my answer.

**Answer:** Use socket.io for python [python-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio)

The reason why built-in sockets or any other websocket library in python won't work is explained in the socket.io website [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v4/#what-socketio-is-not)
Socketio is simply just not a websoket connection. Although they say, it uses websockets for transport internally, the connection is established with HTTP protocol `http://` as opposed to the WEBSOCKET protocol `ws://`. This results in the failure of handshake and the connection fails to be established.