# Python 3.1 - Error while adding a library in Blender

Tags: python, websocket, blender

For this problem (stackoverflow.com/questions/4086435/), I tried to make a Python 3 version of the library python-websocket (github.com/mtah/python-websocket/), here is my code: https://gist.github.com/663175.

Blender comes with his own Python 3.1 package, so I added my file directly in its «site-packages» folder. I get this error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "websocket.py", line 6, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'WebSocket'
```

when running this code in Blender:

```
import sys, os, asyncore, websocket
```

def msg_handler(msg):
  print(msg)

socket = websocket.WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/', onmessage=msg_handler)
socket.onopen = lambda: socket.send('Hello world!')

try:
  asyncore.loop()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  socket.close()

I found that a `__init__.py` is needed so I added but it didn't help…
What I am doing wrong here ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you called your script `websocket.py`, so the import of `websocket` finds the script itself, instead of the installed module by that name. Rename the script to something else (and if it created a `websocket.pyc` file, delete that.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I renamed the script python-websocket.py but I have the same error. There was no websocket.pyc.

Comment: Ok, sorry… It works, I misunderstood what you said. Thanks again !